# Method "baseUrl" does not exist and not was not trapped in __call

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I've implemented the example for display image i do on my controller this function

```
public function confirmAction() {
    $imagefile = $this->baseUrl('ressource/images/pic.png');
    // ...
}
```

and i have this error Method "baseUrl" does not exist and was trapped in __call()

how can i resolve this issue

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can solve it by not using methods do not exist.

Comment: this methode for zend framework how can i called to work in my controller

Answer (score 1):

The `baseUrl()` method is a [`View Helper`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.baseurl) and should not be needed (aka used) in a controller action.

If you really need it there then you'll have to call it on the view object which is usually accessible as `$this->view`. Hence you should be able to use this

```
$imagefile = $this->view->baseUrl('/path/to/file');
```

Comment: how can i get the url file of picture on my Controller Thanks in advance @Adrian World

Comment: Exactly the way I described on the last line. You have to call in on the view object.